# Postgres: CREATE INDEX, but very slowly, to reduce performance hit on rest of database?

Tags: performance, postgresql, index

I have a large production PostgreSQL (9.1) database running on Ubuntu Linux. It is currently being queried and used. However there is another use I need later, and I will need to create a large (hundreds of gigabyte) index. I have run the `CREATE INDEX ...` in a `screen` session and that's running (for several days now), however this is affecting the performance of the rest of the database.

Is there anyway to create an index in postgres, but at a very low priority? So that it'll take longer to create the index, but the performance hit will be less.

- Can I use `renice` the `CREATE INDEX` process? Will that work?
- What about pausing the process for 1 out of every N (e.g. 2 or 3) minutes? Will that break things?
- Can I `ionice` the process? Will that work?

Comment: You can't use `(io)nice` to alter the behavior of just a single database operation, as a DB won't spawn a process for such operations.

Comment: I think the only thing you can try is `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY`.  This won't necessarily be slower or less obtrusive, but at least it avoids blocking changes on the same table.  I also think cannot pause it - how would you achieve it in any case?

Comment: I've tried to play with renicing a PostgreSQL process that was busy with creating an index - I could see no effect.  With a `nice` value of 19, it still could use the most CPU, effectively slowing down some big inserts on other tables.  It is possible that my tests were just wrong - https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Priorities suggests renicing should work.  However, as this very same page suggests, too, you are possibly experiencing not CPU but I/O contention - and in this case no priority can help you.

Comment: You can `ionice` it, and use `CREATE INDEX ... CONCURRENTLY` to reduce the lock level. Note though that `ionice` won't stop the background writer flushing out pages from the index, the cache churn, etc so it's an imperfect solution.

Comment: @Sven nonsense, you can `ionice` a backend. PostgreSQL `fork()`s backends for each connection, it's a multi-processing architecture.

Comment: I know it's probably I/O bottleneck (since that's what `htop`) tells me.

Comment: It is it a normal btree index, or one of the advanced index types?  Can you show the actual create statement?  Also, what settings do you have for wal_level?  what about your maintenance_work_mem?

Comment: @Rory Did you ever find a solution?